# Find general solution of the differential equation (linear algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

How to find the general solution of a differential equation?

$$8y''' + 8y' = 0$$

I literally know nothing about solving differential equations. Honestly I have never been taught about differential equations and I don't know why my professor threw this question into the homework assignmnent.

Comment: Are you trying to write this as a differential equation or a polynomial? Please visit this site: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference to make your question more clear

Comment: @moo I don't understand, why 1,2,3?

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: perhaps you meant $8 y''' + 8 y' = 0$ which is the usual way to indicate third and first derivatives

Comment: yes @WillJagy I don't get how to solve this my professor didn't even go over this

Comment: I edited the post I don't know how to approach this

Comment: OK, so, what do you know about solving differential equations? What examples have you been taught about?

Comment: I literally know nothing about solving dif eq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how a person *might* be able to solve this, even without ever being taught anything about differential equations:

First, such a person might know that constant functions have derivative zero, and might then realize that if $y$ is constant, then $y'$ and $y'''$ are both identically zero, so $8y'''+8y'=0$. Thus, every constant function is a solution.

Second, such a person may know that the derivative of $\sin x$ is $\cos x$, and the derivative of $\cos x$ is $-\sin x$. It follows immediately that the second derivative of $\sin x$ is $-\sin x$, so, if $y=\sin x$, then $y''=-y$, whence $y''+y=0$, whence $8y''+8y=0$. Now differentiating gives $8y'''+8y'=0$, so $y=\sin x$ is a solution.

But then the same argument applies to $B\sin x$ for any constant $B$, so $y=B\sin x$ is a solution. And also, the second derivative of $\cos x$ is $-\cos x$, so, for any constant $C$, $y=C\cos x$ is a solution.

Then, knowing that $(f+g)'=f'+g'$, our hypothetical person may come to realize that $$y=A+B\sin x+C\cos x$$ is a solution for all constants $A,B,C$.

This is where I get stuck – I'm not sure how the person who has never been taught anything about solving differential equations could conclude that *every* solution is of this form, so that we have found the general solution.

Comment: Awsome, Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

This differential equation is equivalent to $y'''+y'=0$, and by making the substitution $u=y'$, we find that it can be expressed as $$u''+u=0$$ Does that look easier to solve?

Comment: Honestly I have never been taught differential equations I don't know why my prof threw this question into the homework assignmnent.

Comment: Ah, that does complicate things a bit... Was Gerry's answer more helpful?

Comment: yes I just upvoted gerrys answer he did a great job